# Firestore: How to remove a field value on double tap of a button

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button where onPressed saves a field value but I want to set it that if the button is then pressed again (which deselects that item so then the text which appears next to the button disappears) that that particular  field value is deleted from the document. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as far as I can understand what you're asking. Please follow up

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TestPageState();
  }
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  bool selected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (selected) {
                  await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Test')
                      .document('test')
                      .updateData({'test': ''});

                } else {

                  await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Test')
                      .document('test')
                      .updateData({'test': '<value-to-be-deleted>'});
                }
                setState(() {
                  selected = !selected;
                });
              },
            ),
            (selected ? Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Text that will disappear'),
            ): Container())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```